# Selenium Python_Using JetBrain_FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C://Python34//Scripts//pythondata.xlsx'

Tags: python, selenium

I trying to perform the data driven testing for `selenium python`  but each time i'm trying to execute i'm facing **Error** 2

```
No such file found
```

can some one tell me whats wrong with following code

and  what file format Selenium Python Support? Is **`.xlsx or .csv`** and do we need to save excel file in any specific 97-2000 format? or normal format will work

Sample Code

```
class fblogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("URL")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_fblogin(self):
        driver=self.driver
        wb=xlrd.open_workbook("C://Python34//Scripts//pythondata.xlsx")
        sheetname = wb.sheet_names()
        sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        i=0
        while (i<2):
            rownum=(i)
        rows = sh1.row_values(rownum)
        UserName = driver.find_element_by_id('UserName')
        driver.find_element_by_id('UserName').send_keys(rows[0, 1])
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        print("The Gbouser name [" + rows[0, 1] + "] is entered")
        Password = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
        driver.find_element_by_id('Password').send_keys(rows[1, 1])
        print("The Password [" + rows[1, 1] + "] is entered")
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.back()
        i=i+1
        Login = driver.find_element_by_name('Login').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Is there a file called pythondata.xlsx in that path? Can you post the whole trace back messge?

Comment: i got following trace back message at terminal windows                  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "loop.py", line 13, in test_fblogin
wb=xlrd.open_workbook("C://Python34//Scripts//pythondata.xlsx")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
f = open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C://Python34//Scripts//pythondata.xlsx'

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no `pythondata.xlsx` in `C://Python34//Scripts`.

You can use `os.path.exists` function to check if it exists:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(file_path)
# update file_path with your own path
```

This returns True for both files and directories.

Comment: Got Following message while executing above script and scripts goes into the infinite mode and at last we have to close terminal  window   @                               `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py:97: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=260, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketType.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0,
laddr=('0.0.0.0', 63786), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 63779)>
  while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):`

Comment: @AmitBhagwat I didn't get your point. Do you have pythondata.xlsx in path C://Python34//Scripts?

Comment: Hi M170897017 Yes i have file in correct path. i tried the script one given by you and  got above error in terminal.